# Sequelize missing FROM-clause entry for table Postgres

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to filter my DataRow objects by where the included DataPoints data is `loc` and sortOrder is `2`. Below is the query I am trying. I keep getting the following error.

`SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dataPoints"`

I have tried setting `required: true` and `duplicating: false` with no luck. I tried these in both the DataRows include as well as DataPoints.

```
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'labId'],
    include: [{
      as: 'dataColumns',
      model: DataColumn,
      attributes: ['id', 'name', 'sortOrder', 'dataType', 'isDate', 'isLocation'],
    }, {
      as: 'dataSets',
      model: Study,
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    }, {
      as: 'dataRows',
      model: DataRow,
      attributes: ['id'],
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          {
            '$dataPoints.data$': 'loc',
          },
          {
            '$dataPoints.sortOrder$': 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      include: [{
        as: 'dataPoints',
        model: DataPoint,
        attributes: ['id', 'sortOrder', 'data'],
      }],
    },],
    order: [
      [{ model: DataColumn, as: 'dataColumns' }, 'sortOrder', 'ASC'],
      [{ model: DataRow, as: 'dataRows' }, { model: DataPoint, as: 'dataPoints' }, 'sortOrder', 'ASC'],
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 15):

Try `required: true` and `duplicating: false` on all the models that you're trying to include. This would solve the problem. Worked for me.

Comment: Worked nice here! Can you explain why this properties work?

Answer (score 8):

If you are here like me who has used a where condition on a column of included table in the **primary where** and got this error, just use this in the options of primary query.

```
{ subQuery: false }
```

Comment: Here's a Sequelize docs on that:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/sub-queries/
Unfortunately it does not explain the case with subQuery when using this kind of "Primary where" search with included models.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code:

```
attributes: ['id', 'name', 'labId'],
    include: [{
      as: 'dataColumns',
      model: DataColumn,
      attributes: ['id', 'name', 'sortOrder', 'dataType', 'isDate', 'isLocation'],
    }, {
      as: 'dataSets',
      model: Study,
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    }, {
      as: 'dataRows',
      model: DataRow,
      attributes: ['id'],
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          {
            '$dataPoints.data$': 'loc',
          },
          {
            '$dataPoints.sortOrder$': 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      include: [{
        as: 'dataPoints',
        model: DataPoint,
        attributes: ['id', 'sortOrder', 'data'],
      }],
    },],
    order: [
      [{ model: model.DataColumn, as: 'dataColumns' }, 'sortOrder', 'ASC'],
      [{ model: model.DataRow, as: 'dataRows' }, { model: DataPoint, as: 'dataPoints' }, 'sortOrder', 'ASC'],
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Looks good approach, though I have not tested myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Required and duplicating set to true and false worked , the issue comes when you try to eager load a model and the search field is not unique, in my case i was able to set my field as unique, getting rid of setting required and duplicating properties in the eager load query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this code

```js
where: {
    [Op.and]: [
        {
            "$dataPoints.data$": "loc",
        },
        {
            "$dataPoints.sortOrder$": 2,
        },
    ],
},
```

to up below `attributes` and change to

```js
where: {
    [Op.and]: [
        {
            "$dataRows.dataPoints.data$": "%loc%",
        },
        {
            "$dataRows.dataPoints.sortOrder$": 2,
        },
    ],
},
```